# How to remove duplicate elements from two lists (pairwise)?

Tags: r, list

I have two very large lists (13000) elements. I would like to remove the duplicates pair-wise, i.e. remove object i in both lists if we find the same as object j.

The function `unique()` works very well for a single list, but does not work pairwise.

```
a = matrix(c(50,70,45,89), ncol = 2)
b = matrix(c(45,86), ncol = 2)
c = matrix(c(20,35), ncol = 2)

df1 = list(a,b,c)
df2 = list(a,b,a)

df3 = cbind(df1,df2)

v = unique(df3, incomparables = FALSE)
```

In the end, the expected result would be `df1 = list(c)` and `df2 = list(a)`. Do you have a good approach for this? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have single element for each component of your list, then you can:

```
df1 <- list("a", "b", "c")
df2 <- list("a", "b", "a")

comp <- unlist(df1) != unlist(df2)
df1[comp]
[[1]]
[1] "c"

df2[comp]
[[1]]
[1] "a"
```

is that what you were looking for?

a more generic (whatever you'd have in your lists) solution using `purrr` would be:

```
comp2 <- !purrr::map2_lgl(df1, df2, identical)
df1[comp2]
[[1]]
[1] "c"

df2[comp2]
[[1]]
[1] "a"
```

Comment: Does it also work when the size of the data differs in the list like I show in the dummy data in the beginning of my code ?

Comment: Also, I need that the output is still a list and that it respect the original order. Is it possible ?

Comment: Nice +1. We don't even need to unlist. This also works `df1 %in% df2`

Comment: It seems your generic solution works! Thank you a lot ! :))))

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Filter(length, Map(function(x, y) x[x != y], df1, df2))
#[[1]]
#[1] "c"

Filter(length, Map(function(x, y) x[x != y], df2, df1))
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"
```